# Can an rvalue reference bind to a function?

Tags: c++, function, c++11, language-lawyer, rvalue-reference

I tested the following code with GCC, Clang, ICC and VS:

```
void f() {}
  
void g(void (&&)()) { }

int main() {
    g(f);
}
```

As we can see, `g` takes an rvalue reference but `f` is an lvalue and, in general, rvalue references cannot be bound to lvalues. That's exactly what **ICC complains** about:

```
error: an rvalue reference cannot be bound to an lvalue
```

**VS also gives an error** but for another reason:

```
error C2664: 'void h(void (__cdecl &&)(void))' : cannot convert parameter 1 from 'void (__cdecl *)(void)' to 'void (__cdecl &&)(void)'
```

This suggests to me that VS is immediately performing a function-to-pointer conversion rather than directly bind the reference to `f`. It's worth mentioning that if I replace `g(f)` with `g(&f)` then the four compilers yield this very same error.

Finally, **GCC and Clang accept the code** and I believe they are correct. My reasoning is based on 8.5.3/5

> A reference to type “cv1 T1” is initialized by an expression of type “cv2 T2” as
>
> — If the reference is an lvalue reference [...]
>
> — Otherwise, [...] **the reference shall be an rvalue reference**.
>
> — If **the initializer expression is a** [...] **function lvalue** [...]
>
> then **the reference is bound to the value of the initializer expression** [...]

Is my interpretation correct (that is, Clang and GCC are compliant for the given reason)?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

> Is my interpretation correct [...]?

**Yes.**

Your interpretation is correct because of the Paragraph of the Standard that you quoted. A further confirmation comes from Paragraph 13.3.3.1.4/3 on reference binding:

> Except for an implicit object parameter, for which see 13.3.1, a standard conversion sequence cannot be
>   formed if it requires binding an lvalue reference other than a reference to a non-volatile const type to
>   an rvalue **or binding an rvalue reference to an lvalue *other than* a function lvalue**. [...]

Paragraph 13.3.3.2/3 contains a further (indirect) confirmation:

> [...] Standard conversion sequence S1 is a better conversion sequence than standard conversion sequence S2 if
>
> — [...]
>
> — S1 and S2 are reference bindings (8.5.3) and S1 binds an lvalue reference to a function lvalue **and S2 binds an rvalue reference to a function lvalue**. [ *Example*:
>
> ```
> int f(void(&)()); // #1
> int f(void(&&)()); // #2
> void g();
> int i1 = f(g); // calls #1
> ```
>
> —*end example* ]

Comment: Indeed. I have tested that before and all four compilers are compliant.