# Why can an rvalue reference bind to a function?

Tags: c++, c++11, rvalue-reference

The following is valid c++

```
void g() {}
void (&&r)(void) = g;
```

See "[Can an rvalue reference bind to a function?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15589842/can-an-rvalue-reference-bind-to-a-function)" thread for details.

My question is: What is the reason that made this possible?

Comment: 1: Function names are rvalues.  2: Why not?

Comment: @asch Function names are lvalues (in C++), not rvalues. (Except for the name of bound class member functions, but which cant be used except as operand of the call operator).

Answer (score 2):

I suspect that it is to provide consistency between plain functions and function objects (including lambdas).

If you make a copy of a pointer or reference to a plain function, the state (`static` locals) is shared, which is somewhat the same as moving (leaving the old copy in an indeterminate but valid state).

Comment: Lambdas don't provide a conversion to reference-to-function types, although they may provide a conversion to pointer-to-function types.

Comment: @hvd: Sure, but I'm thinking of the case where a templated algorithm accepts a function object.  `template<typename Container, typename Predicate> remove_if(Container&, Predicate&&)`-type scenarios

Comment: Ah, okay. For that, I would personally have expected to treat `T &&` as `T &` or `T` if `T` is a function type, just like it does when `T` is an lvalue reference type, but I suppose this is another valid way to solve that.

Comment: @hvd: I would take it as `T` as well, but I can also imagine that some algorithms might somehow care whether the predicate has moveable state.